# the MySQL service on local computer started and then stopped ERROR

Tags: mysql, service

I have installed the MySQL service by running `mysqld --install`. The MySQL service was successfully installed but the problem is that I cannot run the MySQL service, it always gives me this error when attempting to run it: 
 `The MYSQL service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.`

I tried solving this by running `mysqld --initialize` but getting these errors:

**2017-07-21T20:41:06.032938Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).**

**2017-07-21T20:41:06.034939Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.**

**2017-07-21T20:41:06.042944Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting**

Please help (:

thanks!

Comment: Try to run your Windows terminal (cmd) in administrator and locate the MySQL Server file.

Run this command `mysqld --initialize --console` 

This work for me in MySQL Server 8.0.30 and hope it can help you. After successful initialize you can go to Windows service and start MySQL service.

Answer (score 1):

After `mysqld --initialize` try with restarting your machine. It worked for me.

Comment: Dunno what went wrong... but this one solved it in my wamp.